# Solve $X^2\equiv-1\pmod{13}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I've been asked to solve the following equation:

$$X^2 \equiv-1\pmod{13}.$$

I am not sure what to do.

Comment: You can try all possible solutions: $0,1,\dots,12$, though only half of them need to be tested.

Comment: why couldn't x be greater than 12? because if it is, it's equivalent to a number between 0 and 12

Comment: which means that $X^2mod13 \equiv$ ((Xmod13)^2)mod13

Comment: that was what I was trying to put: ${(Xmod13)}^2mod13$

Comment: Does $X$ stand for an unknown integer? (using $x$ for an unknown is more common)

Answer (score 3):

You can try all possible solutions: $0,1,…,12$, though only half of them need to be tested.

For a more sophisticated solution, note that $13=4+9=2^2+3^2$ and so $3^2 \equiv -2^2 \bmod 13$. Since $2\cdot 7 \equiv 1 \bmod 13$, we conclude that $ -1 \equiv -2^2 \cdot 7^2 \equiv 3^2 \cdot 7^2 \equiv (3\cdot 7)^2 \equiv 8^2 \bmod 13$. The other solution is $13-8=5$.

This is a special case of a fact that plays a key role in [Fermat's theorem on primes that are sums of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares):

> A prime $p$ is a sum of two squares iff there is a solution for $x^2\equiv -1 \bmod p$.